# Deserialize ArrayList from String using Jackson ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

Problem Deserializing array as string with Jackson 2

This is a similar problem to [Deserialize ArrayList from String using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247639/deserialize-arraylist-from-string-using-jackson/12716423#12716423)

The incoming JSON (which I can't control) has an element 'thelist' which is an array.
However, sometimes this comes in as an empty string instead of an array:

eg. instead of **"thelist" : [ ]**
it comes in as **"thelist" : ""**

I'm having trouble parsing both cases.

The **'sample.json'** file which works fine:

```
{
   "name" : "widget",
   "thelist" : 
    [
       {"height":"ht1","width":"wd1"}, 
       {"height":"ht2","width":"wd2"}
    ]
}
```

The classes:

```
public class Product { 
    private String name; 
    private List<Things> thelist; 
    // with normal getters and setters not shown
}

public class Things {
        String height;
        String width;
        // with normal getters and setters not shown
}
```

The code that works fine:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test2 {
 public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
        Product product = mapper.readValue( new File("sample.json"), Product.class);
    }
}
```

However, when the JSON has got an empty string instead of an array, ie. **"thelist" : ""** 
I get this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [collection type; class java.util.ArrayList, contains [simple type, class com.test.Things]] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: com.test.Product["thelist"])
```

If I add this line (which works for Ryan in [Deserialize ArrayList from String using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247639/deserialize-arraylist-from-string-using-jackson/12716423#12716423) and seemingly supported by the documentation),

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

it makes no difference.

**Is there some other setting, or do I need to write a custom deserializer?**
If the latter, is there a simple example of doing this with Jackson 2.0.4 ?
I'm new to Jackson (and first time poster, so be gentle). I have done lots of searching, but can't find a good working example.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is that although single-element-to-Array works, you are still trying a conversion from (empty) String into an Object. I am assuming this is the problem you are facing, although without exception it is hard to say.

But there is also `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT` which might do the trick, combined with the first feature. If so, you would get a `List` with a single "empty Object", meaning `Things` instance without values.

Now ideally what should happen is that if you only enabled `ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT`, that would probably do what you want: null value for `thelist` property.

Comment: Thanks, but both suggestions still gave the same exception as before, viz:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [collection type; class java.util.ArrayList, contains [simple type, class com.test.Things]] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: com.test.Product["thelist"])

Comment: So I guess I need to write a custom deserializer?
Can you point me to a simple working example of doing this with Jackson 2.0.4 ?

Comment: It's actually a non-trivial thing (not impossible, just more work). But I think there may be a simpler way: you can override `setThelist` method, make it take `java.lang.Object` (or `JsonNode`), and then handle cases separately. For empty String you get "", for non-empty, `java.util.List` (or `ArrayNode` if using JSON Tree). You will need to use `ObjectMapper.convertValue` for contents for actual binding. But unless this is a common occurence, it is probably less work than a custom Collection deserializer.

Comment: Now, if you do want/need to write custom Collection deserializer, that'd be done by implementing `Deserializers` that overrides method called to construct deserializer, register it using `Module` (simple module won't do for Collection handlers). You can have a look at standard implementations from under `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std` -- there are a few special cases to support type info etc.

Comment: Looking at [https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-620], ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT does work for arrays, Collections and Maps as well. And it does work with data and class shown above too, with or without the other setting. I am using 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT, but it should not differ from 2.0.4 in this area.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was solving similar problem, when I get object like this

```
{  
   "name" : "objectname",
   "param" : {"height":"ht1","width":"wd1"}, 
}
```

from external system so "param" was OBJECT for me which I try to deserilize. When this object was defined in external system it works without problem. But when OBJECT "param" in external system was not defined I get empty ARRAY instead of empty OBJECT

```
{  
   "name" : "objectname",
   "param" : [], 
}
```

which cause mapping exception.
I solve it with creating custom json deserializer which has very good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376304/right-way-to-write-json-deserializer-in-spring-or-extend-it) and for testing of type I used something like

```
    ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
    JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
    if (JsonNodeType.OBJECT == node.getNodeType()) {
        ParamObject result = new ParamObject();
        result.setHeight(node.get("height").asText());
        result.setWidth(node.get("width").asText());
        return result;
    }
    // object in MailChimp is not defined
    return null;
```