# JSONList parsing issue using Jackson in Android

Tags: java, android, jackson

I am trying to parse a JSONList using Jackson parser. If the list contains more than one elements, then the parsing is working fine.

```
String json = "{\"students\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"A\"}, {\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"B\"}]}";
```

If there is only one element, then we will get a json which contains only one json object.

```
 String json = "{\"students\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"A\"}}";
```

At that time I am getting the following error

```
 12-10 15:49:01.527: W/System.err(18923): org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
```

I am using the following code :

```
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Student {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;
}

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class StudentList {
    @JsonProperty("students")
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
}


    public class JacksonTest extends Activity {

    StudentList studentList;
    //String json = "{\"students\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"A\"}, {\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"B\"}]}";
    String json = "{\"students\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"A\"}}";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jackson_test);


        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonFactory jf = new JsonFactory();
        try {
            JsonParser jp = jf.createJsonParser(json);
            jp.setFeature(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS,true);
            studentList = objectMapper.readValue(jp, StudentList.class);

            System.out.println("Size :"+studentList.students.size());
        }
        catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Actually I want to parse very large json which contains large number of lists.

Thanks in advance,
Sudheesh B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I got the solution to solve this. I added the following feature for object mapper.

objectMapper.configure(Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

[Deserialize ArrayList from String using Jackson ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774703/deserialize-arraylist-from-string-using-jackson-accept-single-value-as-array)

This helped me to solve this.

Thanks you M Mohsin Naeem & Faizan for your quick reply.

Answer (score 3):

The class `studentList` should contain the object instead of arrayList

```
public class StudentList {
    @JsonProperty("students")
    public Student students;
}
```

I hope it will resolve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to parse both json using single StudentList. Your answer will parse only the second one. Server will send both json based on the the number of students.

Comment: I think Server is badly designed then -- it should not return element or List, but always List if multiple entries may be returned. Unfortunately this seems like a common server-side anti-pattern... which is why Jackson has support for it (fortunately for you of course! :) )

Comment: @StaxMan : Unfortunately the server guys wont make any changes. I don't have any other option. Any way thanks.

Comment: Yeah, this is unfortunately quite common. It's still good to point that out so that over time people learn... union types like 'either N or N[]' are un-mappable for most programming languages (since it's not "any value" or "any Object" but "either specific Object type or array thereof)