# Spring MVC application not accepting JSON

Tags: spring, post, spring-mvc

I cannot figure out why I cannot post updates to my controller. I am trying to submit json data via a chrome addon. Eventually I will be using angular for the requests. I checked against other stackoverflow articles and it seems I have everything that they suggest.

For what its worth I have a GET request to the same controller that is working without issue.

```
HTTP Status 415 -  The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
```

My server log shows the following

```
INFO - Mapped "{[/service/products/addProduct],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public void com.cr.controllers.ProductsController.addProduct(com.cr.entity.Products)
```

Post to address

```
http://localhost:8082/service/products/addProduct
```

Data being posted

```
{
    "productId": 2,
    "productModel": "Product Model 2",
    "productName": "Product Name 2",
    "dateAdded": 1361880001000,
    "productWeight": 2,
    "productStatus": "Hidden",
    "productTaxClass": {
        "taxId": 2,
        "taxClassTitle": "High Tax Class",
        "taxClassDescription": "This is a high tax class",
        "lastModified": 1361880001000,
        "dateAdded": 1361880001000
    },
    "productImages": {
        "imageId": 2,
        "imageDescription": "Product Image 2",
        "imageTitle": "Image 2",
        "imagePath": "prd_02.jpg",
        "imageRelation": 1
    },
    "productManufacturer": {
        "manufacturerId": 2,
        "manufacturerName": "Factory 2",
        "manufacturerImage": null
    },
    "quantityAvailable": 4,
    "quantityInWarehouse": 4,
    "stockAlert": 1,
    "productCost": 1,
    "productRetail": 1,
    "productPrice": 1,
    "productSalePrice": 1,
    "saleInd": null,
    "productSku": null,
    "backOrderMessage": null,
    "inStockMessage": null,
    "outOfStockMessage": null,
    "manufacturerproductsku": null,
    "productDescriptionId": {
        "productTextId": 2,
        "productTextData": "Este es en espanol",
        "lastModified": 1361793601000
    }
}
```

Controller mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/service/products/addProduct",
        consumes = "application/json",
        method= RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void addProduct(@RequestBody Products products){
    productsDao.createProduct(products);
}
```

web.xml

```
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cr</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>cr</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

_ UPDATE *_*_

I started using amplify to do my requests because I wanted to be sure that it was not the chrome addon.  I am getting a 400 now.  Below is the error showing on my server.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of com.cr.entity.Products out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@28d528d5; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.cr.entity.Products out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@28d528d5; line: 1, column: 1
```

Here is the amplify definition and request.

```
 amplify.request.define("addRequest", "ajax", {
            url: "service/products/addProduct",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });
        amplify.request({
            resourceId: "addRequest",
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
            success: function () {
                alert("success")
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("fail")
            }
        });
```

Data:

```
var jsonData = [{
    "productId": 4,
    "productModel": "Product Model 2",
    "productName": "Product Name 2",
    "dateAdded": 1361880001000,
    "productWeight": 2,
    "productStatus": "Hidden",
    "productTaxClass": {
        "taxId": 2,
        "taxClassTitle": "High Tax Class",
        "taxClassDescription": "This is a high tax class",
        "lastModified": 1361880001000,
        "dateAdded": 1361880001000
    }
}];
```

Comment: Can you check if your client is sending the proper Content-Type header, application/json

Comment: Spring MVC depends on Jackson (either 1 or 2) in order to handle JSON input or output. Do you have any jackson library in your classpath ?

Comment: Post your client side code which submits the data, the issue seems to be in the client side

Comment: I added client side code, as well as a new error message

Comment: @CostiCiudatu  I did have jackson but I was missing a property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to add the following to the jsonConverter bean.

```
<property name="prefixJson" value="false"/>
```

Final Bean was as follows

```
 <bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="prefixJson" value="false"/>
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
    </bean>
```

[Another Stack Overflow Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247639/deserialize-arraylist-from-string-using-jackson)